# How can you turn on the led light on the iphone 4?

Tags: iphone, camera, led, iphone-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn on torch/flash on iPhone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4)

I just want to be able to turn on the led light.  Is there a simple way to do this, or am I going to need to, say, set up the phone to take a video, simulate it videoing with the light on, but not save the video?  Something like that?  Thanks.

Comment: the Flash tag is reserved for Flash programming and workflow

Comment: Seems like someone figured it out... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DauJ1LpqrNg

Comment: yeah i've seen that.  i dont think he'd tell me how he did it tho lol

Comment: Please see my answer here for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/3367424#3367424

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked fine for me.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


- (void) turnTorchOn: (bool) on {

  Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
  if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
  AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
  if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if (on) {
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
        torchIsOn = YES;
    } else {
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
        torchIsOn = NO;            
    }
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
  }
}
```