# Turn on torch/flash on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I know that the only way to turn on the flash and keep it on on iPhone 4 is by turning the video camera on. I'm not too sure of the code though. Here is what I am trying:

```
-(IBAction)turnTorchOn {
    AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *videoCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoCaptureDevice error:&error];

    if (videoInput) {
        [captureSession addInput:videoInput];

        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        [videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_current_queue()];

        [captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];

        [captureSession startRunning];

        videoCaptureDevice.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOn;
    }   
}
```

Does anybody know if this would work or am I missing anything? (I don't have an iPhone 4 yet to test on -just trying out some of the new API's).

Thanks

Comment: I've written a Torch plugin that works for Cordova 2.2.0. You can find it here: https://github.com/tomschreck/iOS-Torch-Plugin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the `lockforConfiguration` is set in your code, where you declare your `AVCaptureDevice` is a property.

```
[videoCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
```

Answer (score 72):

Here's a shorter version you can now use to turn the light on or off:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([device hasTorch]) {
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];  // use AVCaptureTorchModeOff to turn off
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

UPDATE: (March 2015)

With iOS 6.0 and later, you can control the brightness or level of the torch using the following method:

```
- (void)setTorchToLevel:(float)torchLevel
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (torchLevel <= 0.0) {
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        }
        else {
            if (torchLevel >= 1.0)
                torchLevel = AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel;
            BOOL success = [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:torchLevel   error:nil];
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

You may also want to monitor the return value (`success`) from `setTorchModeOnWithLevel:`.  You may get a failure if you try to set the level too high and the torch is overheating.  In that case setting the level to `AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel` will set the level to the highest level that is allowed given the temperature of the torch.

Comment: This definitely made things simpler and more responsive for me in my attempts to toggle the flash.  I had used the method that iWasRobbed posted, but it wasn't very responsive.

Answer (score 38):

iWasRobbed's answer is great, except there is an **AVCaptureSession** running in the background all the time. On my iPhone 4s it **takes about 12% CPU power** according to Instrument so my app took about 1% battery in a minute. In other words if the device is prepared for AV capture it's not cheap.

Using the code below my app requires 0.187% a minute so the battery life is more than 5x longer.

This code works just fine on any device (tested on both 3GS (no flash) and 4s). Tested on 4.3 in simulator as well.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

- (void) turnTorchOn:(BOOL)on {

    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (on) {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
                torchIsOn = YES;
            } else {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
                torchIsOn = NO;            
            }
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should work on all i.e. it should work from 5.0 and it shouldn't crash below that.

Comment: thank you, it sure works on 5.0 and 5.1, I'm worried about 4.3

Answer (score 18):

**See a better answer below:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054088/308315

---

**Old answer:**

First, in your AppDelegate .h file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    AVCaptureSession *torchSession;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureSession * torchSession;

@end
```

Then in your AppDelegate .m file:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize torchSession;

- (void)dealloc {
    [torchSession release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {

    // initialize flashlight
    // test if this class even exists to ensure flashlight is turned on ONLY for iOS 4 and above
        Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
        if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {

            AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

            if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

                if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) {

                NSLog(@"Setting up flashlight for later use...");

                    AVCaptureDeviceInput *flashInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
                    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

                    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

                [session beginConfiguration];
                    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

                    [session addInput:flashInput];
                    [session addOutput:output];

                    [device unlockForConfiguration];

                    [output release];

                [session commitConfiguration];
                [session startRunning];

                [self setTorchSession:session];
                [session release];
                    }

            }

        }
    } 
    return self;
}
```

Then anytime you want to turn it on, just do something like this:

```
// test if this class even exists to ensure flashlight is turned on ONLY for iOS 4 and above
Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
    [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];

    [device unlockForConfiguration];

}
```

And similar for turning it off:

```
// test if this class even exists to ensure flashlight is turned on ONLY for iOS 4 and above
Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
    [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: In the appdelegate.m file, you should enclose the `init` method's content with something such as: `if ((self = [super init])) { ... } return self;`

Comment: This is too combursom and keeping the session consumes battery. Try method below from Tibidabo

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 6.0 and above, toggling torch flash on/off,

```
- (void) toggleFlash {
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        [device setFlashMode:(device.flashActive) ? AVCaptureFlashModeOff : AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
        [device setTorchMode:(device.torchActive) ? AVCaptureTorchModeOff : AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

P.S. This approach is only suggestible if you don't have on/off function. Remember there's one more option `Auto`. i.e. `AVCaptureFlashModeAuto` and `AVCaptureTorchModeAuto`. To support auto mode as well, you've keep track of current mode and based on that change mode of flash & torch.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 2.0 version:

```
func setTorchLevel(torchLevel: Float)
{
    self.captureSession?.beginConfiguration()
    defer {
        self.captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
    }

    if let device = backCamera?.device where device.hasTorch && device.torchAvailable {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            defer {
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            }

            if torchLevel <= 0.0 {
                device.torchMode = .Off
            }
            else if torchLevel >= 1.0 {
                try device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(min(torchLevel, AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel))
            }
        }
        catch let error {
            print("Failed to set up torch level with error \(error)")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//import fremework in .h file 

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
{
 AVCaptureSession *torchSession;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)AVCaptureSession *torchSession;


-(IBAction)onoff:(id)sender;

//implement in .m file

@synthesize torchSession;

-(IBAction)onoff:(id)sender
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash])
    {
        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) 
        {
            [button setTitle:@"OFF" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            AVCaptureDeviceInput *flashInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];

            AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
            AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

            [session beginConfiguration];
            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
            [session addInput:flashInput];
            [session addOutput:output];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
            [output release];
            [session commitConfiguration];
            [session startRunning];
            [self setTorchSession:session];
            [session release];
        }
        else 
        {
            [button setTitle:@"ON" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [torchSession stopRunning];
        }
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [torchSession release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This work's very well.. hope it help's someone !

```
-(IBAction)flashlight:(id)sender {

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) {

            [sender setTitle:@"Torch Off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            AVCaptureDeviceInput *flashInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
            AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

            AVCaptureSession *cam = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

            [cam beginConfiguration];
            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];

            [cam addInput:flashInput];
            [cam addOutput:output];

            [device unlockForConfiguration];

            [cam commitConfiguration];
            [cam startRunning];

            [self setTorchSession:cam];
        }
        else {
            [sender setTitle:@"Torch On" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [_torchSession stopRunning];
        }
    }
}
```