# I just want to turn the flash on for stitching photo's I'm trying to use AVCaptureDevice and AVCaptureFlashModeOn

Tags: cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0, camera, ios4

```
-(IBAction)turningFlashOn:(id)sender
{
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *videoCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoCaptureDevice error:&error];

if (videoInput) {
    [captureSession addInput:videoInput];



    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_current_queue()];
    [captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
    [captureSession startRunning];
    videoCaptureDevice.torchMode = AVCaptureFlashModeOn;
}
}
```

I am being asked to use lockForConfiguration but it doesn't work or maybe i'm using it wrong. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
if([videoCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration]) {
  [videoCaptureDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
  [videoCaptureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
 }
```

Comment: [videoCaptureDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];

or just release your AVCaptureSession object. Which ever is more appropriate.

Comment: You should probably call `[session stopRunning];` before releasing the session.  See my post here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/3367424#3367424

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)flashLightOn {


    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device hasFlash] == YES) {

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }

    }
}

-(void)flashLightOff {


    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device hasFlash] == YES) {

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }

    }

}
```