# iPhone 4's LED Backlight

Tags: iphone, video, uiimageview

I am trying to figure out how to use the UIIMagePicker or some way to use the iPhone 4's Backlight LED. I am trying to use a UIView with a button on it to turn the LED on & off without showing any video. Is this even possible? Any help?

EDIT

I've been using AVCaptureDevice class or at least trying to. When it comes to importing #import  It tells me it isnt valid.

The code I am trying to use is  http://twitpic.com/23lv9v

Comment: Please see my answer here for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/3367424#3367424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable the camera for that. Look at the [AVCaptureDevice Class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and possibly AVCaptureTorchMode and  AVCaptureFlashMode.

Comment: There's no need to even show the video when you're using the AVCaptureDevice, let along place a UIView over it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to have to takew a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set [videoCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
then you can turn on the torch...

See the docs: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I see. Ill try that when I get home later on :)

Thanks

Comment: BTW! I tried your code in my XCode, in Simulator the code crashes, but, i tried in the device mode, and it works!.

Comment: Hey Gustavo Barrientos.

Mine builds now but crashes when I click the button getting SIGBART

Comment: runs on the Simulator? or in the iDevice?
try checking the hasTorch.