# Make a button start the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

So I have made a custom UIButton and added it to the code and made the connections in  interfacebuiler. I want the button to work as a on and off switch, how do I do this correctly? I'm a beginner at iphone development and this is for a school project for this class I'm taking during the summer to get a head start for next semester.

So if anyone can help me understand how to do this the right way and maybe write comments in the code. Thanks for all the help.
David H.

Here's my code:

```
//
//  FlashlightViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface FlashlightViewController : UIViewController {

    AVCaptureSession *torchSession;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}

-(IBAction)pressButton:(id) sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureSession *torchSession;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

@end
```

Here is the .m file

```
//
//  FlashlightViewController.m
//

#import "FlashlightViewController.h"

@implementation FlashlightViewController
@synthesize torchSession;
@synthesize button;


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    [session beginConfiguration];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];

        AVCaptureDeviceInput *flashInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
        if (flashInput){
            [session addInput:flashInput];
        }

        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        [session addOutput:output];
        [output release];
        [session commitConfiguration];

        [session startRunning];
    }

    [self setTorchSession:session];
    [session release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.button = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [TorchSession release];
    [button release];
    [super dealloc];
}
-(IBAction)pressButton : (id) sender{

}
@end
```

Comment: Please see my answer here for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/3367424#3367424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `@interface` section (.h), you also need `IBOutlet IBAction pressButton;`. Then, in Interface Builder, in the inspector (outlet section), select File's Owner, and connect `pressButton:` to the UIButton's `Touch Up Inside` action.

To toggle the torch state, add `BOOL torchAlreadyOn;` to the `@interface` section (.h). Then, move your `viewDidLoad` custom code to the `pressButton` method. Then, at the end of the `pressButton` method, add:

```
if (torchAlreadyOn) {
    torchAlreadyOn = NO;
}
else {
    torchAlreadyOn = YES;
}
```

Then, everywhere where you set the torch state to on, enclose it in an if...else statement which checks the `BOOL`:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

[session beginConfiguration];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

    if (torchAlreadyOn) {
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
    }
    else {
        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
    }
    [device unlockForConfiguration];

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *flashInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
    if (flashInput){
        if (!torchAlreadyOn) {
            [session addInput:flashInput];
        }
        else {
            [session removeInput:flashInput];
        }
    }

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    if (!torchAlreadyOn) {
        [session addOutput:output];
    }
    else {
        [session removeOutput:output];
    }
    [output release];
    [session commitConfiguration];

    [session startRunning];
}

[self setTorchSession:session];
[session release];
```

Comment: jrtc27, is there anyway to control the heat when the flash is on? the device get really hot!!!
Or is it just they way it is?

Comment: Sadly, the heat is out of your control, as the LED is either on or off.

Comment: Just an fyi.. just tried this snippet and it seems to freeze up the app when you toggle it off.

Comment: Please see my answer here for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/3367424#3367424

Comment: Posted this off the top of my head - kudos @IWasRobbed - +2

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem actually? There is a built in [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object. And if you want to create a custom one, then you can keep track of a bool flag and toggle that in the button handler.