# Turn cameraFlash On before takePicture?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Can I programmatically turn on the *camera flash* **on** a new iPhone 4 device, **before** taking a picture with `-takePicture`?

I'm developing a photo taking app for iOS 4 and want to power on the flash light **before** the user takes a picture, so they can see the effect of the flash in advance.

The problem seems to be that for the flash light to stay on, you'll need to set the `torchMode` on and this is only possible in 'video mode' (`UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo`), while you can only ask the `UIImagePickerController` to `takePicture` when it is on 'photo mode' (`UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto`).

So, the following works, but only shows the flash light when taking a picture:

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;

    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.image", nil];
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

And this also works (shows the torch the whole time), but then I cannot take a picture.

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;

    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

When I try the `toggleTorch` code found here: [Turn on torch/flash on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4#3367424) there seems to not be any live video feed in the `UIImagePickerController`.

Are these `UIImagePickerController` and `AVCaptureSession` compatible with each other? or are you supposed to choose for either one or the other?

And does anybody know a workaround to get both the flash mode on (or `torchMode`) and to be able to `takePicture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the WWDC 2010 sessions (specifically 409) where they go into functionality like the one you're looking for.

Essentially you need to move away from UIImagePickerController if you're looking to perform these custom camera functions and move towards AVFoundation classes.

Comment: The other point is to have the LED flash on at any instance OTHER than taking a picture (i.e. before or after taking a pic) you need to use the Torch (AVCaptureTorchMode) and not the Flash.

Comment: Thanks, that pointer to that session was very useful in explaining all about the AVFoundation framework! Especially the AVCam Demo example code does all the stuff I would like to do (and more).