# iPhone app issue from inactive to active state

Tags: iphone, multitasking, flashlight

Hi guys I have an issue with a flashlight app.
I have a button to turn on/off the flash. Also I the viewdidload turn on the app.
When I press the home button and then click on my app again the app dont turn on the flashlight so I have used the applicationDidBecomeActive. This method turn on the flash but if I click on the button to turn it off the app is crashing.

this is the appdelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    Just_A_LightViewController *mvc = [[Just_A_LightViewController alloc] init];
    [mvc toggleFlashlight];
    [mvc release];
}
```

and this is the viewcontroller.m:

```
- (void)toggleFlashlight{
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSLog(@"toggle");

if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
    NSLog(@"torch and flash");

    if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) {
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *flashInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];

        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];


        AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

        [session beginConfiguration];

        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];

        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];

        [session addInput:flashInput];

        [session addOutput:output];

        [device unlockForConfiguration];

        [output release];

        [session commitConfiguration];

        [session startRunning];

        [self setAVSession:session];
        [session release];
        NSLog(@"toggle true");

    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"toggle false");
        [AVSession stopRunning];
        [AVSession release], AVSession = nil;}
}
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self toggleFlashlight];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"button");
[self toggleFlashlight];

}
```

The nslogs is for troubleshooting. After pressing the home button and relaunching the app even if the flash is turned off the console shows the "toggle false"
What I am doing wrong here?
Crashlog:

```
Sun Mar 13 23:00:05 unknown ReportCrash[313] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process mediaserverd[21]
Sun Mar 13 23:00:06 unknown ReportCrash[313] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/mediaserverd_2011-03-13-230005_TheMaster.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Sun Mar 13 23:00:06 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.mediaserverd) Job appears to have crashed: Bus error
Sun Mar 13 23:00:06 unknown mediaserverd[314] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [mediaserverd] (550.52)
Sun Mar 13 23:00:06 unknown mediaserverd[314] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WinterBoard.dylib
Sun Mar 13 23:00:06 unknown mediaserverd[314] <Warning>: WB:Notice: WinterBoard
Sun Mar 13 23:00:06 unknown com.apple.mediaserverd[314] <Notice>: MS:Warning: message not found [UIImage defaultDesktopImage]
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace from the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is causing your issue, but it might be relevant:

Your `toggleFlashlight` method is doing too much each time you toggle -- it's doing setup each time which only needs to be done once. More details in the example here:

[Turn on torch/flash on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/3367424#3367424)

See the answer by iWasRobbed. So try doing the setup stuff only once, and then when you need to toggle, call `setTorchMode` and `setFlashMode` as shown in that example.

Comment: thanks for the advice but I cant figure out how to split this code. any suggestions?

Comment: Just edited my answer to make the hyperlink more obvious, as it was a bit unobvious. Can you see iWasRobbed's answer at that link? It's pretty self-explanatory if you see what his strategy was.