# Problem with the camera flash iphone

Tags: iphone, camera

I have a switch that if I activate it, I turn on the camera flash and if you turn off, turn off (default is off)

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{   

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        return;

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo];

    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

    picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];  

}

- (IBAction) onChangeSwitch:(id)sender

{

    switch(interruptor.on){
        case YES:
            picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
            break;
        case NO:
            picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
            break;
    }
}
```

Looking online, I've seen the code I have is to turn the flash simply and not to start or stop the torch from the iPhone camera.

I've seen it done with the AVCaptureDevice [Turn on torch/flash on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/3367424) # 3367424 I do not know now how could adapt that to my code.

Does anyone know and gives me a hand?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)flashLightOn {


    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device hasFlash] == YES) {

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }

    }
}

-(void)flashLightOff {


    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device hasFlash] == YES) {

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I turn the light (a.k.a. torch) on & off:

```
- (void) setTorchOn:(BOOL)isOn
{
    AVCaptureDevice* device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil]; //you must lock before setting torch mode
    [device setTorchMode:isOn ? AVCaptureTorchModeOn : AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

I'm pretty sure you'll need to link to the AVFoundation framework.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I'll try to see if I have luck, but I think if I have picker, I can not mix with AvCaputre .. to see if I have luck.

Thank you very much again.