# iPhone LED Torch light off while dismiss UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a torchlight option in my iPhone app. This is working fine. I am using `UIImagePickerController`(Camera Mode) to take photographs. I can turn on the torch light before staring the camera, however when I dismiss the camera the torchlight also gets switched off. Does the torchlight work only in camera/video mode?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3367424/919545

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava thanks for your answer. In my app when the user select the Torch button the torch light getting switched off. But, if the user came from Camera mode the Torch light automatically switched off. Is this right or wrong. Please help me. Thanks.