# Is this any method to turn on Tourch light in Cammera Mode not Video mode?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn on torch/flash on iPhone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4)

i make app for camera open it's turn on in flash light..
not open camera in video mode?

so if any method provide by ios to turn on flash light in did load method?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4

Answer (score 1):

**Duplicate** of [Turn on torch/flash on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/7964777#7964777)

Thanks @progrmr for notifying.

Comment: That code snippet isn't enough to turn the LED on or off, it only changes a BOOL value.

Comment: @progrmr thanks for info. can you expand the answer (community wiki). thanks.

Comment: The answer is in another question [on StackOverflow here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7964777/1693173)