# Need to restrict my app to only run on devices with an L.E.D

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've built a flashlight app, how can I put a restriction in place so it will only install on devices with a L.E.D? I presume `UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities`, but not sure which key/value to use.

Comment: If the device doesn't have an LED as per `[device hasTorch]` you should instead make the screen completely or almost completely white. It makes a pretty good flashlight then.

Comment: I removed the Xcode tag because the question has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `camera-flash` key of the `UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities` properties to YES to make sure it will only install on devices that contain a "camera flash" (usually the torch)

Comment: This is a much better solution than @patapple as this simply won't let the app be installed in the first place.

Comment: Leon is correct.  You can find a list of all of the `UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities` keys in the documentation:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3   Information on setting the key in the .plist can be found in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete answer: [Turn on torch/flash on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/)

To check if the device has the torch or not, use this code:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if ([device hasTorch]) {
     // The device has a torch
}
```