# How to use flash to take picture on custom camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, avcapturesession

I've looked everywhere and I can't figure out how to toggle the flash in such a way when I take a picture it flashes 4 times like it does on the iPhone camera.

I'm using this function to toggle the flash...

```
func toggleFlash() {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
        } else {
            device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
        }
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
}
```

And I use this function to take a picture...

```
func didPressTakePhoto(){
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in

            if sampleBuffer != nil {

                var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                var dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

                var image:UIImage!

                if self.camera == true {
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                } else {
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored)

                }
                self.tempImageView.image = image
                self.tempImageView.hidden = false
            }


        })
    }


}
```

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32301753/4503700

Comment: @CharlesTruluck No, I'm trying to make it so that I can incorporate the flash when I take a picture.

Comment: Whose sorry! I thought you meant it wasn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very messy way. Not clean.

```
func didPressTakePhoto(){

toggleFlash()
sleep(1)
toggleFlash()

if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
    videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
        (sampleBuffer, error) in

        if sampleBuffer != nil {

            toggleFlash()

            var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
            var dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
            var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

            var image:UIImage!
            if self.camera == true {
                image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

            } else {
                image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored)

            }
            self.tempImageView.image = image
            self.tempImageView.hidden = false
        }


    })
}


}
```

It's very messy, just an idea.
You could also use an NSTimer to fire it twice.

Comment: Thanks for this! But the timing is a little bit off. And I've been fiddling around with the sleep and I haven't been able to get it right. What should I set it too?

Comment: You could try changing `while i <= 2` to `while i <= 4`. Tell me how that looks.

Comment: I'll go try that! Also it appears that I can't set sleep to a double.

Comment: It appears the flash is to slow. And the picture is taken before the flashes finish.

Comment: Updated code. Basically toggling it on when the button is pressed, then off when the image was captured.

Comment: Still doesn't work because the picture is taken before the flashes end.

Comment: So you want it to: Flash. Flash. Picture & Flash?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92073/discussion-between-charles-truluck-and-john-doe).